# How to fetch the particular value from the response object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, object

I am having very basic question: but I am unable to find how to fetch a value from this

```
{
    "content": {
        "laptops": {
            "brands": {
                "company": "xyz",
                "specification": {
                    "name": {
                        "description": "xyzName",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "status": {
                        "description": "abcName",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to fetch the brand value from the above response:
ServiceClass:

```
getSample(): Promise<> {
    return http
      .get("http://localhost:8080/user")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("sample",response);
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        throw error;
      });
  }
}
```

useEffect:

```
 useEffect(() => {
      service
      .getSample()
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("response", data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);
```

In console I am getting the complete response but I only want to fetch the **"brands"** Can any one help me with this!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: You should be able to dig into your data object to get that. Something like `data.content.laptops.brands`.

Comment: Thats the first thing I tried to write data.content, it gives an error: Property does not exist

Comment: If `response.data` is a string you will need to parse it to a JavaScript object with `JSON.parse`. So, `const content = JSON.parse(data);` and then you can get the brands from `content.laptop.brands`.